# Custom types importing each other

Tags: python, numpy, types

Let's say I have a Python package with custom types, `CustomType1` and `CustomType2`. They are defined as classes, and both subclass a `BaseType`. They are defined in separate files, as the classes are huge (because of all the builtin class-functions like `__setitem__`). Now, these classes need to refer to each other. For example, each initializer checks the type of the input data, and if it's the other type, convert it. So, an example class:

```py
class CustomType1(BaseType):
    def __init__(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, CustomType2):
            pass # todo
```

As you might imagine, this is gonna be a hurdle when importing. Since both are defined in a package, I can just `import package.path.to.custom_type1`, but if I have to type this everytime, the code is gonna be cluttered. The traditional `from .custom_type2 import CustomType2` doesn't work either, as that leads to circular dependencies import errors.

What is the best approach to tackle this? Still use `import package.path.to.custom_type1` and then typing `package.path.to.custom_type1.CustomType1` everytime? Or is there a solution which looks like NumPy, where you can just type `np.int8` no matter where? I can also use local imports, but since the initializer can be called a thousand of times, that would be extremely slow.

Maybe it's some magic with `__init__.py` and `__all__ = []`, but so far no success.

EDIT: forgot to mention that they can also *call* each other, rather than only type checking. For now, I've implemented a method with interfaces, which suits well for type checking.

Comment: Check this out: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/369146/how-to-avoid-bidirectional-class-and-module-dependencies

Comment: The use of interfaces seems promising, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The thing with polymorphism is that if your function takes an argument of BaseType, you *never* want to be in the situation where you have to check for different subtypes.

Rather, your BaseType should declare common methods for any of the things you need to do in that conversion (eg returning certain data, etc), and your different subtypes should then implement them. For example:

```
class BaseType:
    def get_data(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()
    def set_data(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class CustomType1(BaseType):
    def __init__(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, BaseType):
             self.set_data(data.get_data())

class CustomType2(BaseType):
    def get_data(self):
        pass
```

This would let your CustomType1 initializer ask CustomType2 to perform whatever conversion is necessary to return the right data, without CustomType1 having to know anything about CustomType2.

(For this to be possible, of course there needs to be some "neutral" form that both types can be converted to and from, but if there isn't, then it would likely be incorrect to give them a common base type in the first place.)